# is this correct json url query for this json file

Tags: json

I have json data described like:

```
{
"device" : "{device}",
 "time" : {time}
}
```

Is this url query correct for it?

```
http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/mydata/sigfoxdata.php/?id={device}&time={time}
```

**EDIT**
Validated JSON

```
{
    "device": "{device}",
    "time": "{time}"
}
```

**Example I used:**
[image]

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Assuming a valid JSON and assuming that you want to convert each object property to an URL parameter then answer is still no because { has to be escaped (but also many other characters than please use a proper escape function)

Comment: I think you mentioned about not use of quotes around "time" for json,  typo error sorry.

Comment: Also `{time}` isn't a valid thing.

Comment: So it need to be within quotes too? It will be something like that 2018-07-14 19:43:37

Comment: OK, I validate it now from jsonlint. Bec I am not handling it but need to query & get parameters' values so I was least concerned about json. Please now see query url. Here json:


{
 "device": "{device}",
 "time": "{time}"
}

Comment: As I said...no...(at least for the sample strings you're providing). `{` has to be encoded and, in general, if you're concatenating strings to build an URL you should always encode them (I don't know if you're doing this client or server-side but many languages have a function for that).

Comment: On client side. I added an image in OP. It's from tutorial I am using. They used nothing like that i.e. encoded. At least I think so.
https://www.disk91.com/2014/technology/internet-of-things-technology/using-sigfox-callback-api-to-create-your-own-application/

Comment: Don't confuse what you can do with that _tool_ with what's valid _anywhere_. It seems that `{}` is used as placeholder to replace values from a JSON object in a plain string (URL, in this case). You should consult the documentation of that specific tool (or simply try...) but I'd safely assume that values are already encoded (and no, URL won't be `?id={device}&time={time}` but it's encoded version, IF values of `device` and `time` requires encoding).